# A notion similar to contractibility in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a topological spaces
$(X,\tau)$ and a subset $S\subseteq X$, we say that $X$ is  $S$-contractible if

$$X\simeq X/R$$

Where $$R= S^2 \cup ( \Delta_X/ \Delta_S )$$

Where $\Delta$ is the diagonal.

The idea is that pulling $S$ to a single point doesn't change $X$. I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to classify all spaces $X$ with a subset $S\simeq X$ such that $X$ is $S$-contractible?
2. More of a soft question as someone with not too much experience in topology, does this definition make sense, and is it capturing what I want it to?

Some examples regarding the first are that $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the first property, and a doughnut and a sphere don't, also any infinite discrete (and likely indiscrete too) space satisfies this.

Comment: What's $\mathbb{\Delta}$? And what do you mean by $S^2$?

Comment: If $\Delta$ are diagonals, I guess you meant $\Delta_X \setminus \Delta_S$ instead of $\Delta_R \setminus \Delta_S$

Comment: The standard notation is $X/S$ (collapsing $S$ to a single point).

Comment: What do you mean by "$\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the first property"? The property requires a pair of space and subspace. Do you claim that $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies this property with respect to *any* subspace $S$? That couldn't be further from truth. And also the doughnut, sphere, and actualy any space satisfies this with trivial $S=\{*\}$ point. Those examples are also manifolds, and so they satisfy the property with non-trivial $S$ as well, e.g. small enough ball.

Comment: Btw, there's a theorem that if $X$ is a CW complex, $A\subseteq X$ is "good enough" (techincally it is closed and the inclusion $A\to X$ is a cofibration), and $A$ is contractible then the natural map $X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @freakish apologies for the sloppy question, the first property I intended to be viewed as a property of a space only, where the property is "There exists a subset of the space $X$ such that... "

Comment: @freakish That is an interesting result, that seems related to what I'm asking, I think it differs in that I'm asking about homeomorphisms, and it is not required to be the quotient that is the homeomorphism, but I would not be surprised if it turns out the existence of a homeomorphism implies that the quotient is a homeomorphism

Comment: @Carlyle as I explained in my previous comment: the existence of such subset for **any** $X$ is trivial, take $S=\{x\}$ for any point $x\in X$. And a nontrivial subset will often exist as well. You claim that donought and sphere don't have such subset? They have lots of, every small enough ball will be such subset. In general every manifold will have infinitely many such subsets.

Comment: @freakish, I'm not sure I follow, it is only a trivial case where we have $\{x\} \simeq X$

Comment: Wait, so you want both $X\simeq S$ and $X\simeq X/S$?

Comment: @freakish Indeed, I believe this is clear from the question?

Comment: @Carlyle not really. Also the term "$$-contractible" is confusing, since this has nothing to do with being contractible. For example the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) has this property. It is more related to being "self similar" to be honest. Anyway, I really doubt there's a way to classify such spaces.